# How can I get the current connected user's indentity in my Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2, acl

I've followed this tutorial http://ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-acl-setup-in-5-minutes-tutorial/ to settle Acl in my project.  I have to modify my Module.php, then I have to request current connected user's role.

**So my question is, how can I get the current connected user's indentity in my Module.php ?**

I would like to do something like :

```
$userRole = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')->getStorage()->read()->statut
```

My actual code :

```
public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {
$route = $e -> getRouteMatch() -> getMatchedRouteName();
///////// current connected user's role
$userRole = 'guest';

if (!$e -> getViewModel() -> acl -> isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
    $response = $e -> getResponse();
    //location to page or what ever
    $response -> getHeaders() -> addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/404');
    $response -> setStatusCode(303);

}
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MvcEvent has access to the `Application`, which in turn has access to the `ServiceManager`, so...

```
public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {
    $route = $e -> getRouteMatch() -> getMatchedRouteName();
    ///////// current connected user's role
    // get the main app
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    // get the service manager 
    $sm = $app->getServiceManager();
    // get role from auth service
    $userRole = $sm->get('AuthService')->getStorage()->read()->statut

    if (!$e -> getViewModel() -> acl -> isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
        $response = $e -> getResponse();
        //location to page or what ever
        $response -> getHeaders() -> addHeaderLine('Location', $e -> getRequest() -> getBaseUrl() . '/404');
        $response -> setStatusCode(303);

    }
}
```